# setting Maximum Fragment Length Negotiation for SSL records using curlpp

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl, curlpp, wolfssl

I have requirement to set Maximum Fragment Length Negotiation for SSL records in my C++ application. I am using curlpp and wolfSSL for SSL support.

In wolfSSL I can find wolfSSL_UseMaxFragment(), and wolfSSL_CTX_UseMaxFragment() which supports this feature. However I am not able to find any such option to set in curlpp in [options.hpp](https://github.com/datacratic/curlpp/blob/master/include/curlpp/Options.hpp).

I am very new to curl and curlpp. Please let me know how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libcurl does not offer any API to set this config as of today.

If you really need this, I would propose two different ways forward with different amounts of work and features:

1. just add the code yourself to libcurl's WolfSSL's backend to make it happen automagically. Although that would be a change the curl project wouldn't want...
2. write up a way to set this via the standard libcurl API and propose this change to the curl project and then we could work on seeing how feasible it is and what it would take to support in other TLS backends as well

*libcurl truly is the sum of all our best efforts!*

Comment: thanks @Daniel. I am using the APIs provided by wolfSSL now. For the second point sorry that I wont be able to implement in near future.